# C# System.IO.InvalidDataException zip file

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'Number of entries expected in Central Directory Ending does not match the number of entries in the Central Directory.'

I'm getting this error on a code that i'm making "for fun" when i try to extract an zip file to a folder. Help ;-;

here's my situation: i made a Drag and Drop panel that recieve a file with a unique extension (the file is a zip but i changed the extension to test). Then the program will get the first line of text in the archive, and will create a folder to extract the files with the name given on that first line. But it gets that error on the extract code

```
string[] Arquivo = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
        foreach (string arquivo in Arquivo)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(arquivo);
            string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(arquivo);
            string line = string.Empty;
            if (allLines.Length >= 1)
            {
                line = allLines[0];
            }
            string Diretorio = @"C:\CommunicAlt\" + line;
            MessageBox.Show(Diretorio);
            if (!Directory.Exists(Diretorio))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Diretorio);
            }
            Path.ChangeExtension(arquivo, ".zip");

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(arquivo, Diretorio);     //<--Here
```

Comment: How large is the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the problem is: the zip archive has a new line with a text to create a directory, but the visual studio can't extract it if the number of lines on the archive is different drom the default... so it won't extract.
The solution was to leave the zip archive untouched and create a new file with the config info.